# critical inductance value when designing a buck converter

Tags: inductance

From the formula used in this literature from Texas Instruments
http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva057/slva057.pdf - Page 15

Here are my requirements:

Vo-Output voltage(v)    98
Vi(max)-Maximum input voltage(v)    120
Ts-Time period(sec) 0.000001
Io(crit)-Minimum current to maintain continuous conduction(A)   0.1

[image: Critical Inductance formula]

Calculating the inductor value i get it:
**L(min)    8.98E-05 H**

So am i correct in assuming that any value of inductance above L(min)will ensure BUCK operation in continuous mode?
If that is the case ,can i remove the catch diode/free wheeling diode,without causing damage to my MOSFET during operation?

Comment: I am interested in how you got a negative result.  Are you sure you evaluated the 1- (Vo/Vi) term correctly?

Comment: You might be interpreting the formula incorrectly. Vi(max) is the maximum input voltage, not the maximum current as you appear to assume. For a buck regulator, Vi > Vo, so the term (1-Vo/Vi) should never be negative.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that,i realized that and changed it,pls check first post. The value will be positive once i change it.L(min) comes to around **8.98E-05 H**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operating in continuous mode doesn't mean you can forget about the diode - how will the inductor remain in continuous conduction when the power transistor switches off? It relies on the diode for circulating the stored energy into the capacitor.